# В каких случаях используется слово «прокатать»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов, глаголы

Как лучше писать: *мы **прокатали** лист броневой* или *мы **откатали** лист броневой*?

Comment: Этот глагол встречается в тексте песни «прокати меня на тракторе»: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahJC0NuFHLo

Answer (score 1):

Попробую ответить на давнишний вопрос.

◙ Случаи для использования глагола [*прокатать*](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) (*св., кого-что*) такие:
**1.** Разгладить при помощи катка, валька. *Прокатать бельё.*
**2.** *Техн.* Подвергнуть прокатке.
**3.** Катать (2 зн.) кого-либо в течение какого-либо времени. *Прокатать детей целый час на лодке.*

◙ Немножко металловедения

> Сталь становится броней не при помощи введения в сплав дополнительных материалов, а с помощью **специальной закалки**.
> Обработка подразумевает соблюдение особых термических режимов в течение установленных промежутков времени, которые изменяют структуру материала на молекулярном уровне.

◙ Немножко технологии
Изготовление современных видов бронестали, конечно же, засекречено.
Общее представление о том, каким образом из стали получают броневую, можно получить из статей о самых первых ее видах.
[Гарвеевская броня](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F)
[Броня Круппа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0)

Лишь редкие виды современной брони подвергаются "добавочной" прокатке.

> Отличные характеристики этого металла достигнуты с помощью легирования хромом, молибденом, никелем, марганцем, кремнием, ванадием и т. д. Полученные листы подвергались термической обработке и упрочнению путем дополнительной **прокатки**.

◙ Немножко выводов
Обычную сталь *прокатывают*; броневую, если надо, — тоже *прокатывают*.
Так что я бы выбрала первый вариант: *мы **прокатали** лист броневой.*

◙ Немножко примеров
*Во второй половине XIX века на Ижорских заводах впервые в России стали тянуть медные трубы без спайки и **прокатали** первую **броневую плиту** весом 170 пудов* (Путь к лидерским позициям (2004) // «Металлы Евразии», 23.04.2004).

*Так были построены: броневой стан «4500»  (эвакуирован  из  Мариуполя), на котором уже 1 ноября 1941 года был **прокатан** первый **броневой лист**; среднелистовой стан «2350» эвакуированного завода «Запорожсталь»...* (из сборника «Говорят герои великой Победы. Диалог поколений. Магнитка – подвиг тыла»).

Answer (score 0):

Если лист катаный, то ***"прокатать"*** вполне уместно в профессиональной речи.
"Откатать" - это что-то из другой сферы...

Но если это песня у вас или что-то подобное, то лучше техническими терминами её  не нагружать в принципе.

Вообще контекст хотелось бы видеть, больно уж странное построение у фразы.

Comment: Не соглашусь с аргументом по песне: для специфического жанра (как саундтрек к [Производственному фильму](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC) ) или песни-пародии, отличное слово.

Comment: @AntonMenshov У меня нет аргументов. ))) Ни по песне, ни вообще. Максимум - тезис, который я могу лишь своей имхой подкрепить. Равно как и вы.